# .apk file installed and worked on 2.2 android device well but .apk not installing in android 4.0.4 iball tab

Tags: android

**MY MANIFEST**

App run well in android 2.2 device well but getting error when try to installing in android

4.0.4 device,i tested by changing the properties of the app also.

**BUILD TARGET:**

package="com.example.androidactionbar"

android:versionCode="1"

android:versionName="1.1" >

**USING SDK:**

```
<uses-sdk


    android:minSdkVersion="3"


      android:maxSdkVersion="15" 


    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

**SUPPORT SCREEN RESOLUTION:**

```
    android:anyDensity="true"


    android:largeScreens="true"


    android:normalScreens="true"


    android:smallScreens="true" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >


</uses-permission>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >


</uses-permission>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />


<application


    android:icon="@drawable/applauncher"


    android:label="CarKonect"


    android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" >


    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    <activity


        android:name=".ActionBarAppActivity"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_app" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".HomeActivity"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_app" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".SearchActivity"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_app" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Writetodealer"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_app" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".FeedBackForm"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_app" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".ScheduleService"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_app" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".R"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_r" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".CustomerLogin"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_login" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".CarKonect"


        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".CustomAdapter"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_adapter" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".JSONParser"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_jsonparser" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Comment"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_comment" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".ExpandAnimation"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_expand_animation" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".CollapseAnimation"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_collapse_animation" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Animation"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_animation" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".MainActivity"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_animation" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".ServiceCallAsyncGet"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Common"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_common" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".ExpandListView"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_expand_list_view" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".JsonPost"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_json_post" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Json"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_json_post" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Normal"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_normal" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".ServiceCallAsyncCommon"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_service_call_async_common" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".OneNormal"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_one_normal" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Asyncall"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_asyncall" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".NormalTwo"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_normal_two" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".OneNormalValue"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_normal_two" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".AsyncallOne"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_normal_two" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".AsyncallTwo"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_asyncall_two" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".ResetPassword"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".JsonParserTwo"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_json_parser_two" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".CustomListViewAdapter1"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_list_view_adapter1" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".Schedule"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_schedule" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".JsonParserOne"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_json_parser_one" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".TestActivity"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".SingleClick"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity


        android:name=".SingleClickComment"


        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >


        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: define "getting error". format.

Comment: will please tell me where should i placed this getting error format in manifest file

Comment: @prasanth you should add what error you get to your question here, not to the manifest :)

Comment: i sended .apk file through gmail and try to install in android 4.0.4 iball tab then  getting the application not installed error but it work well in android 2.2 samsung device

Comment: @ZAPL:i am using google maps in app

Comment: you probable don't have the maps library on your device

Comment: then please tell me solution

Comment: Please tell what is the error you are getting while trying to install your apk file

Comment: application not installed this is the error i am getting in device.

Comment: @almuneef my tab android 4.0.4 iball slide model i6012 is not having gps feature is this is the problem

Comment: Please try with my answer below

Comment: please suggest me still now getting application not installing error

Comment: @njzk2 thank you for ur suggition my device not supporting the maps library after removing the maps library from my manifest file it will work correctly thank u

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: i tried that step also but again it shows application not installed message

Comment: <application
         android:icon="@drawable/applauncher"
         android:label="CarKonect"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" >
         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: i am using maps library in my app

Comment: Pls try to install the apk using a terminal
Doing so you will get a reason why the app cannot be installed
and post that message here

Comment: the persons who are using the android 4.0.4 iball tab they have no facility of integrating the maps library(google maps) so try to google maps in that.